# Cancelling function when clicked elsewhere than target div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing inventory mechanics on my webgame and I want to complicate stuff a little.

In order to open the gate you need to find boltcutters. When you find it, you need to click on boltcutters and then on a chain to break it, and that's the part I have working.
But I want to implement some kind of function that if after clicking boltcutters I click anywhere but on the chain I want to run a function cancelling chain function (changing color) and displaying "Cant use it here" msg for example.

So in short, I need to find a solution where (pseudocode):

```
If(boltcutters_clicked){
if(clicked_on_chain){
 openthedoor()} 
else {
 cancelBoltcutters()}
```

Here is the part of the code I have for now, if thats helping:

> // chain mechanics

```
var boltcutters_used = false;
document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').onmousedown = function(){
    boltcutters_used = true;
    document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').style.border = "1px solid red";
}

var boltcutters_found = false;
document.getElementById("chain").onmousedown = function(){
    if(boltcutters_used){
        alert('you open the door');
    } else if(!boltcutters_found){
        alert("I need to find something to break this chain...")
    } else {
        alert("Boltcutters could do the trick")
    }
}
```

Thanks to the idea mentioned below I came up with following solution:

```
var last_clicked = null;
var test=0;
window.onclick = function (e) {
last_clicked = e.target;

if(boltcutters_used == true){
    test++;
}
if(boltcutters_used == true && last_clicked !== document.getElementById("chain") && test >1){
    alert("Can't use it here");
    boltcutters_used = false;
    test=0;
}
```

}

And it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Maintain the last clicked item

Have a variable to store the `last clicked` element

On `window click` update the value of that variable

Check for this variable in your `chain` event handler

```
var last_clicked = null;
window.onclick = function (e) {
    last_clicked = e.target;
}

var boltcutters_used = false;
document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').onmousedown = function(){
    boltcutters_used = true;
    document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('item_boltcutters').style.border = "1px solid red";
}

var boltcutters_found = false;
document.getElementById("chain").onmousedown = function(){
    if(boltcutters_used){
        if(last_clicked === document.getElementById("item_boltcutters")) {
            alert('you open the door');
        } else {
            alert("You should use the bolt cutters on this");
        }
    } else if(!boltcutters_found){
        alert("I need to find something to break this chain...")
    } else {
        alert("Boltcutters could do the trick")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in order to understand it I need to research it a little, since im only beginner in JS, I'll let you know if that worked!

Comment: Okay, I researched it and understand it I guess and while it's useful and im gonna definitely use such function later it doesnt solve my problem, because I still cant achieve my goal, that is displaying "cant use it here" when clicked elsewhere than on the chain. I would need something like "if next_clicked != chain" and so on.

Comment: Solved it thanks to your idea though, edited the main post if you want to see, Thank you!